# Question on an apparent solipsistic usage of the "quotative って"

Tags: grammar

> A: Be careful not to make a mistake.
>
> B: I know that without being told.
>
> A: 間違えないように気を付けてね。
>
> B: 言われなくても分かってるって。

In the final って in B's answer, I am supposing that this is the "quotative って," used as a way to emphasize B's own voice. Is he metaphorically quoting himself?

Perhaps the implication is:

> "Yeah, like I said, I know that without being told."

Is this line of thinking correct? Would someone explain this use of って?

Is there a Japanese term for this って?

*Apologies in advance for my colorful usage of the word solipsistic. If you think of a better title feel free to change it.

Comment: この辞書では、３[終助詞]の４番に当たります　http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/147762/m0u/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, he is quoting himself for emphasis (although I don't know what is solipsistic about it). I think of it as an ellipsis of something like

> 言われなくても分かってる**って言ってるでしょ**。
>   **I'm telling you,** I get it even without being told.

There is also

> 言われなくても分かってる**ってば**。

which means roughly the same thing. (See sense 2 of [this dictionary entry](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%B0).)

Comment: Thanks. I used solipsistic as he was referring to himself, though that is stretching the meaning of the word.